# Looping through output of json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get this solution to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30400111/4532066

Where I have a simple SELECT menu:

```
<select class='form-control' id='builders' name='builder_id'>
    <option value="1">Oracle</option>
    <option value="2">SQL</option>
</select>
```

I want to use the ID from the first SELECT to change the contents of a second SELECT, with an ID of "regions"

This is the jQuery code that I'm working with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#builders').change(function() {
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    $.get("ajax_cats.php", {
      'builder_id': currentValue
    }, function(data) {
      var regions = $.parseJSON(data);
      $('#regions').empty();
      for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
        var regionOption = '<option value="' + regions[i]['fld_label'] + '">';
        regionOption += regions[i]['fld_label'];
        regionOption += '</option>';
        $('#regions').append(regionOption);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is the contents of "ajax_cats.php"

```
 $sql = "SELECT cats.fld_label
           FROM tbl_b_cats cats
          WHERE cats.fld_parent = ? 
       ORDER BY cats.fld_label";

/* initialise */
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

/* prepare */
if (!$stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    throw new Exception("Error preparing statement: $stmt->error, SQL query: $sql");
}

/* bind */
if (!$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['builder_id'])) {
    throw new Exception("Error binding parameter: $stmt->error");
}

/* execute & store */
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

/* 404 for no results */
if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit;
} else {

    $regions = array();

    /* get results */
    $stmt->bind_result($fld_label);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $regions['fld_label'][]   = $fld_label;
    }

    //print_r(array_values($regions));
    //$bob = json_encode($regions);
    //r($bob);
    echo json_encode($regions);

}
/* free and close */
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();

$conn -> close();
```

I have confirmed that the data returned by "ajax_cats.php" is in JSON format - e.g.

```
{
    "fld_label": ["AP", "AR", "EAM", "GL", "HR", "INV", "Other", "PA", "PO", "SysAdmin"]
}
```

I think the problem is in the jQuery, with this section:

```
var regions = $.parseJSON(data);
$('#regions').empty();
for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
    var regionOption = '<option value="'+regions[i]['fld_label']+'">';
    regionOption += regions[i]['fld_label'];
    regionOption += '</option>';
    $('#regions').append(regionOption);
}
```

From reading on S/Overflow yesterday, the "length" option only works if you're using an array.

Because if I do:

```
console.log(regions.length);
```

It returned "undefined"

I wondered how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Use `regions.fld_label`...You have `fld_label` as key of the object,..Or  `regions[i]['fld_label']` is an array..What do you want to display as options... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some adjustements needed:

1. Change `var regions = $.parseJSON(data);` to `var regions = $.parseJSON(data).fld_label;`. This will get you the array of regions.
2. Then change `regions[i]["fld_label"]` to `regions[i]`

**Code snippet:**

```js
var data = "{ \"fld_label\": [\"AP\", \"AR\", \"EAM\", \"GL\", \"HR\", \"INV\", \"Other\", \"PA\", \"PO\", \"SysAdmin\"]}";

var regions = $.parseJSON(data).fld_label; // To get the array ["AP", "AR, ...]

$('#regions').empty();

for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
  var regionOption = '<option value="' + regions[i] + '">';
  regionOption += regions[i];
  regionOption += '</option>';
  $('#regions').append(regionOption);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="regions"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you @Pierre C. I really appreciate you help

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to find the length of your JSON is with the key like this:

```
var length = regions.fld_label.length;
```

This will give you the length of the JSON key's value, using this you can loop into values for a particular key in the JSON.

Put it like this and hopefully you won't get that error

```
var regionOption = '<option value="'+regions.fld_label[i]+'">';
```

Comment: Thank you - that has worked, as it returns the number of elements. However, I now get a new error: *TypeError: regions[i] is undefined* on this line: *var regionOption = '<option value="'+regions[i]['fld_label']+'">';*